# python json5 and json package inconsistent deal with surrogate pair

Tags: json, python-3.x, unicode-escapes, surrogate-pairs, json5

```
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
#-*-coding:utf8-*-
#python version 3.11.4

import json5
import json

d = json5.loads('{"\\ud83d\\ude03": "ok"}')
print(d) # output: {'\ud83d\ude03': 'ok'}

d = json.loads('{"\\ud83d\\ude03": "ok"}')
print(d) # output: {'': 'ok'}
```

Is this a bug, a feature, or is my usage wrong?

surrogate pair is supported which described in this document:
[RFC 8259 - The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data ...](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259).
JSON5 is a superset of JSON,it should be compatible with json. so i think it's not a feature.

Comment: That looks like a `json5` package bug. [The JSON5 spec](https://spec.json5.org/#escapes) matches the JSON spec on this point.